# Scribd text encrypted (need to copy text)

Tags: encryption, scribd

I was trying to copy the text from here: http://madhuvable.org/glossary-2/ ...
As you can see, it appears alright that way, but when copied and pasted, you will see that it is actually encrypted. I've been searching how to somehow decrypt this but I've yet to find a solution. Any help? Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple character substitution cypher.  For example: "MOBILE" is "LKC@EH" so M=L, O=K, B=C, I=@, L=E, E=H